# django update modelform

Tags: django, modelform

I have a model as follows

```
class UserPrivacy(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    profile = models.SmallIntegerField(default=1, choices=PRIVACY_TYPE)
    contact = models.SmallIntegerField(default=1, choices=PRIVACY_TYPE)
    friends = models.SmallIntegerField(default=1, choices=PRIVACY_TYPE)
    location = models.SmallIntegerField(default=1, choices=PRIVACY_TYPE)
```

My modelform is as follows

```
class PrivacyForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserPrivacy
        exclude = ('user','location')
```

My function looks like this to display and update the form.

```
def show_privacy(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PrivacyForm(request.POST, instance=User.objects.get(pk=request.session['id']))
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

    else:
        form = PrivacyForm()

    return render_to_response('settings_privacy.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

My user_id in the db is 1.. but when I post a form it never gets updated. I know form.save() gets called due to putting a print there and it gets shown in the dev server.

Comment: I might be a bit rusty on forms, but why are you passing a User object into the UserPrivacy form? Wouldn't you normally pass in a UserPrivacy instance?

Comment: i want to update items based on the logged in user.

Comment: But how do the fields in the User model map to the fields in the UserPrivacy model? Are you just trying to set the user field of the UserPrivacy form?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Andy Hume was correct in the comments to your question.

You have a ModelForm based on the UserPrivacy model, yet you are passing it an instance of User.

What you want to do is this:

```
form = PrivacyForm(request.POST, instance=UserPrivacy.objects.get(user=request.user)
```