# Django-powered library checkout system

Tags: python, django, forms, checkout

I am working on a library system to manage certain items in our office, I don't need a full-blown integrated library system so I decided to hand roll one with Django.

Below is a simplified version of my model:

```
class ItemObjects(models.Model):

# Static Variables
IN_STATUS        = 'Available'
OUT_STATUS       = 'Checked out'
MISSING          = 'Missing'
STATUS_CHOICES   = (
    (IN_STATUS,  'Available'),
    (OUT_STATUS, 'Checked out'),
    (MISSING,    'Missing'),
)

# Fields
slug             = models.SlugField(unique=True)
date_added       = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
last_checkin     = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, null=True)
last_checkout    = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, null=True)
last_activity    = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, null=True)
status           = models.CharField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=IN_STATUS, max_length=25)
who_has          = models.OneToOneField(User, blank=True, null=True)
times_out        = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, editable=False)
notes            = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=500)
history          = models.TextField(blank=True, editable=False)
pending_checkin  = models.BooleanField(default=False)
pending_transfer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

At first I was using a method on `ItemObject` to process checking out an item to a user and `who_has` was an `EmailField` because I couldn't get a `CharfField` to populate with the logged in user's name, but I figured using a `OneToOneField` is probably closer to the "right" way to do this.. While `who_has` was an `EmailField`, the following method worked:

```
    def check_out_itemobject(self, user):
        user_profile                     = user.get_profile()
        if self.status == 'Available' and self.who_has == '':
            self.status                  = 'Checked out'
            self.who_has                 = user.email
            self.last_checkout           = datetime.datetime.now()
            self.last_activity           = datetime.datetime.now()
            self.times_out               += 1
            if self.history == '':
                self.history             += "%s" % user_profile.full_name
            else:
                self.history             += ", %s" % user_profile.full_name
            if user_profile.history == '':
                user_profile.history     += self.title
            else:
                user_profile.history     += ", %s" % self.title
        else:
            return False # Not sure is this is "right"
        user_profile.save()
        super(ItemObjects, self).save()
```

Now that I am using a `OneToOneField` this doesn't work, so I started looking at using a subclass of `ModelForm` but none of the cases I saw here on SO seemed to apply for what I am trying to do; my form would be a button, and that's it. Here are some of the questions I looked at:

[Django: saving multiple modelforms simultaneously (complex case)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033121/django-saving-multiple-modelforms-simultaneously-complex-case/5033242#5033242)

[(Django) (Foreign Key Issues) model.person_id May not be NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281935/django-foreign-key-issues-model-person-id-may-not-be-null)

[django update modelform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631722/django-update-modelform)

So was I on the right track with a sort of altered save() method, or would a ModelForm subclass be the way to go?

EDIT/UPDATE: Many thanks to @ChrisPratt!

So I am trying to get Chris Pratt's suggestion for showing ItemHistory to work, but when I try to render it on a page I get an `AttributeError` that states "'User' object has no attribute 'timestamp'". So my question is, why is it complaining about a `User` object when `last_activity` is an attribute on the `ItemObject` object ?

My view:

```
@login_required
def item_detail(request, slug):
    item      = get_object_or_404(Item, slug=slug)
    i_history = item.last_activity
    user      = request.user

    return render_to_response('items/item_detail.html',
                              { 'item'     : item,
                                'i_history': i_history,
                                'user'     : user })
```

I do not see why a `User` object is coming up at this point.

EDIT2: Nevermind, history is clearly a M2M field whose target is User. That's why!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming users will log in and check out books to themselves, then what you most likely want is a `ForeignKey` to `User`. A book will only have one `User` at any given time, but presumably `User`s could check out other items as well. If there is some limit, even if the limit is actually *one* per user, it would be better to validate this in the model's `clean` method. Something like:

```
def clean(self):
    if self.who_has and self.who_has.itemobject_set.count() >= LIMIT:
        raise ValidationError('You have already checked out your maximum amount of items.')
```

Now, you checkout method has a number of issues. First, `status` should be a defined set of choices, not just random strings.

```
class ItemObject(models.Model):
    AVAILABLE = 1
    CHECKED_OUT = 2
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (AVAILABLE, 'Available'),
        (CHECKED_OUT, 'Checked Out'),
    )

    ...

    status = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=AVAILABLE)
```

Then, you can run your checks like:

```
if self.status == self.STATUS_AVAILABLE:
    self.status = self.STATUS_CHECKED_OUT
```

You could use strings and a `CharField` instead if you like, as well. The key is to decouple the static text from your code, which allows much greater flexibility in your app going forward.

Next, `history` needs to be a `ManyToManyField`. Right now, your "history" is only who last checked the item out or what the last item the user checked out was, and as a result is pretty useless.

```
class ItemObject(models.Model):
    ...
    history = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='ItemHistory', related_name='item_history', blank=True)

class ItemHistory(models.Model):
    CHECKED_OUT = 1
    RETURNED = 2
    ACTIVITY_CHOICES = (
        (CHECKED_OUT, 'Checked Out'),
        (RETURNED, 'Returned'),
    )

    item = models.ForeignKey(ItemObject)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    activity = models.PostiveIntegerField(choices=ACTIVITY_CHOICES)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-timestamp'] # latest first
```

Which then allows you to get full histories:

```
some_item.history.all()
some_user.item_history.all()
```

To add a new history, you would do:

```
ItemHistory.objects.create(item=some_item, user=some_user, activity=ItemHistory.CHECKED_OUT)
```

The `auto_now_add` attribute ensures that the timestamp is automatically set when the relationship is created.

You could then actually get rid of the `last_checkout` and `last_activity` fields entirely and use something like the following:

```
class ItemObject(models.Model):
    ...
    def _last_checkout(self):
        try:
            return self.history.filter(activity=ItemHistory.CHECKED_OUT)[0].timestamp
        except IndexError:
            return None
    last_checkout = property(_last_checkout)

    def _last_activity(self):
        try:
            return self.history.all()[0].timestamp
        except IndexError:
            return None
    last_activity = property(_last_activity)
```

And, you can then use them as normal:

```
    some_item.last_checkout
```

Finally, your checkout method is not an override of `save` so it's not appropriate to call `super(ItemObject, self).save()`. Just use `self.save()` instead.

Comment: Just a couple comments: 1) I'd recommend `related_name='history'` for `ItemObject.history`, since it's the `User`'s history. 2) could you do `some_item.history.create(user=some_user, activity=ItemHistory.CHECKED_OUT)` instead of going through `ItemHistory.objects`? 3) I'd recommend using the `@property` decorator for `last_checkout`.

Comment: Thanks Chris Pratt! I guess I should have clarified, but we are not imposing a checkout limit. I like what you did with the history, going to give it a try now!! EDIT: also thanks to Mike DeSimone!

Comment: I chose `item_history` instead of `history` for the related name because it's foreseeable that `User` might have other "histories" associated with it. `ItemObject` will ever only have one "history", so the shortened form was fine there.

Comment: @Chris, I didn't mention this because I didn't think it was relevant, but the `ItemObject` model is actually an `Abstract` model which I then subclass to specific item types. Am I correct in thinking I would need to make a separate `ForeignKey` for each `ItemObject` subclass, or will one `ForeignKey` to `ItemObject` suffice?

Comment: Oh, yeah, that would be a problem. You would need a generic foreign key on the through table, but I don't think that's possible. Even if it was, it'd probably be nightmare to maintain. You could try creating a foreign key for each subclass on the through table with `blank=True, null=True` on each, but that seems clunky as well. Your only other option would be to forgo making the class abstract and use MTI (multiple table inheritance), or it's possible that depending on what your subclasses do, you might be able to make those proxy models and just have one table for `ItemObject`.

Comment: Thanks Chris, the subclasses introduce new fields that are specific to that item. For example a Game would have a developer and a platform whereas a book would not, and so forth. So given that, I think that one `ForeignKey` to `ItemObject` may work.

Comment: You can only have one `ForeignKey` to `ItemObject` if you make `ItemObject` an actual model instead of abstract, and use MTI. You can't create a foreign key to an abstract model.

Comment: I see, time to RTFM a bit more then. Thanks!